# How can I make flash cards using Stacks and Queue in java

Tags: java, data-structures

I am not sure how to implement stacks and Queues can you tell me if this class implements it in the right way. As it will perform LIFO and FIFO because it runs fine but I just wanna make sure. And can you also tell me the difference between implementing it with arraylist vs stacks and queues. Thank you

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Queue;

public class Deck {
private File file;
private String fileName = "Untitled";
private boolean Modified;
private boolean TestRunning;
private int numCorrect;
private int numWrong;

static Queue<QuizCard> quizCardList = new LinkedList<>();
static Queue<QuizCard> quizCardList2 = new LinkedList<>();


static int curr_size;  

 Deck()  
{  
    curr_size = 0;  
}  

static void push(int x)  
{  
    curr_size++;  


    quizCardList.add((QuizCard) quizCardList);


    while (!quizCardList.isEmpty())  
    {  
        quizCardList.add(quizCardList.peek());  
        quizCardList2.remove();  
    }  

    // swap the names of two queues  
    Queue<QuizCard> q = quizCardList;  
    quizCardList = quizCardList2;  
    quizCardList2 = q;  
}  

static void pop(){  


    if (quizCardList.isEmpty())  
        return ;  
    quizCardList.remove();  
    curr_size--;  
}  

static QuizCard top()  
{  
    if (quizCardList.isEmpty())  
      //  return -1;  
    return quizCardList.peek();
    return null;  
}  

static int size()  
{  
    return curr_size;  
}  





/** addQuizCard - creates and adds a QuizCard to quizCardList */
void addQuizCard(String q, String a){

    if(q.length() == 0){
        q = " ";
    }
    if(a.length() == 0){
        a = " ";
    }
    quizCardList.add(new QuizCard(q, a));
}



/** readFile - loads in the data from a saved deck into quizCardList */
void readFile(String fileLocation){
    file = new File(fileLocation);
    setFileName(file.getName());
    assert file.canRead();
    try(BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))){
        int letterNumber;
        StringBuilder dataToParse = new StringBuilder();
        while((letterNumber = input.read()) != -1){
            dataToParse.append((char) letterNumber);
        }

    }catch(IOException ioEx){
        ioEx.printStackTrace();
    }
}


void save(String fileLocation){
    file = new File(fileLocation);
    assert file.canWrite();
    try (BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file))) {
        for(QuizCard quizCard : quizCardList){

        }
    }catch(IOException ioEx){
        ioEx.printStackTrace();
    }
}


void shuffle(){
    Collections.shuffle((List<?>) quizCardList);
}


String getFileLocation(){
    return file.getAbsolutePath();
}

String getFileName(){
    return fileName;
}

boolean getIsModified(){
    return Modified;
}

boolean getIsTestRunning(){
    return TestRunning;
}

int getNumCorrect(){
    return numCorrect;
}

int getNumWrong(){
    return numWrong;
}

List<QuizCard> getQuizCardList(){
    return (List<QuizCard>) quizCardList;
}


void setFileName(String fileName) {
    if(fileName.contains(".")){
        fileName = fileName.split("\\.")[0];
    }
    this.fileName = fileName;
}

void setIsModified(boolean newValue){
    Modified = newValue;
}

void setIsTestRunning(boolean newValue){
    TestRunning = newValue;
}

void setNumCorrect(int newValue){
    numCorrect = newValue;
}

void setNumWrong(int newValue){
    numWrong = newValue;
}

}
```

Comment: Try coding something and then when you hit a brick wall show us what you have tried

Comment: I have just added the code. Thank you

Comment: Just don't reinvent the wheel - it's a fun thing to try to see if you can make, but if you want people to actually use it, anki is kind of _amazingly great_ at this already.